# Testcafe, how to click a button on a modal popup?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm struggling to define a selector in TestCafe that clicks that button on the left called "start a car damage claim". This button appears on a modal popup
.[image]

My code looks like

```
class PortalDashboard {

constructor(){
    //Selectors Portal
    this.welcome_user_message = Selector('#welcomeBack') 
    this.topbar = Selector('#stateNavbar')
    this.footer = Selector('.row footerSectionOne')   
    this.policy_summary = Selector('#policySummaryList') 
    this.logout_button = Selector('.logoutBtn')
    this.my_claims = Selector('a[href="./claims"]')  
    this.view_motor_policy_details_link = (Selector('#policySummaryDetails_M0014157733').find('#claimLink_0'))
    
    //Start a claim - Modal popup
    this.motor_claim_modal = Selector ('#carAccidentDialog')
    this.property_claim_modal = Selector('.claimDialog')
    this.call_us_button = Selector('#callUsDesktop')
    this.start_claim_button = Selector('#defaultFocus')
    this.modal_popup=Selector('panel-body center')
}
async clickStartClaim(claimtype){
    await t
    .expect(this.modal_popup.exists).ok('Element not found', { timeout: config.general.shortTimeout })
    .expect(this.call_us_button.exists).ok('Element not found', { timeout: config.general.shortTimeout })
    .expect(this.start_claim_button.innerText).contains(claimtype)
    .click(this.start_claim_button)
    .setPageLoadTimeout(config.general.shortTimeout )

}
```

TestCafe fails at the moment to find the selectors `modal_popup` on the popup.

Which selector can I use so Testcafe can find the popup and then click the button?

Error displayed:

```sh
   1) AssertionError: Element not found: expected false to be truthy

 async clickStartClaim(claimtype){
         88 |        await t
       > 89 |        .expect(this.modal_popup.exists).ok('Element not found', { timeout: config.general.shortTimeout })
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is not with the button itself but with the modal. Note that the error is in the assertion:

> .expect(this.modal_popup.exists).ok

Your `modal_popup` variable is `Selector('panel-body center')` but you have not declared if is `class` (.) or `id` (#).

So your variable into constructor should be:

```
this.modal_popup = Selector('.panel-body center')
                             ^
                            This
```

If you don't use `.` or `#`, TestCafe will look for the value as tag (`div`, `button`...) and `panel-body` is not a tag, is a class name.